# Output parameter from job when done

Tags: powershell

**UPDATE**
I'm not struggeling with this error `An event with the name 'StateChanged' does not exist` - See the full code at TRYOUTS (the last code piece) below

---

**original text**

As mentioned before, I'm doing a code for automatically format and transfer files to multiple USB thumbdrives. **And it´s done in parallel/async**

Now the issue is that I want to output the drive letter of each USB as they completes / job is done. That letter is stored in a var/param inside the job function, but I don't know how to write it out when job is done.

I have an `Register-ObjectEvent` that fires when each USB is completed in formatting and transfering.
The script works really well and writes out the line `USB slot = Job...`

But I want to have my `$driveLetter` from inside `$formatDrive` written out in the line `USB slot = $driveLetter`.

Heres my code. Look for the lines `$formatDrive` and `$jobEvent`.

```
#Requires -version 2.0
ipmo storage
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange

$formatDrive = {
    Param($driveLetter)
    Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) "Erase disk..."
    $source = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\test"
    Format-Volume -DriveLetter $driveLetter[0] -NewFileSystemLabel "test30" -FileSystem exFAT -Confirm:$false
    robocopy $source $driveLetter /S
    return $driveLetter
}

Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) " Beginning script..."
do {
    $newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
    $eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
    $eventTypeName = switch ($eventType) {
        1 {"Configuration changed"}
        2 {"Device arrival"}
        3 {"Device removal"}
        4 {"docking"}
    }
    if ($eventType -eq 2) {
        $driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
        $driveLabel = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
        Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) "USB igang = " $driveLetter
        # Execute process if drive matches specified condition(s)
        $formatDrivejob = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $formatDrive -ArgumentList $driveLetter
        $jobEvent = Register-ObjectEvent $formatDrivejob StateChanged -Action {
            Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) (' USB slot = Job #{0} ({1}) complete.' -f $sender.Id, $sender.Name)
            [media.SystemSounds]::("Hand").Play()
            $jobEvent | Unregister-Event
        }
    }
    Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1-eq1) #Loop until next event
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

I've tried just writing it out inside the end of `$formatDrive` - which didn't work as it's running in background.
Also tried with `return` as you can see in `$formatDrive`

TRYOUTS:

```
#Requires -version 2.0
ipmo storage
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange

$formatDrive = {
    param($driveLetter)
    write-host (get-date -format s) "Erase disk..."
    $source = "C:\Users\jbh\Desktop\test"
    Format-Volume -Driveletter $driveLetter[0] -NewFileSystemLabel "test30" -FileSystem exFAT -Confirm:$false
    robocopy $source $driveLetter /S
    return $driveLetter
}

write-host (get-date -format s) " Beginning script..."
do{
$newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
$eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
$eventTypeName = switch($eventType)
{
1 {"Configuration changed"}
2 {"Device arrival"}
3 {"Device removal"}
4 {"docking"}
}
# initialize the array
$formatDrivejob = @()
if ($eventType -eq 2) {
    $driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
    $driveLabel = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
    Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) "USB igang = " $driveLetter
    # Execute process if drive matches specified condition(s)
    $formatDrivejob += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $formatDrive -ArgumentList $driveLetter
    $jobEvent = Register-ObjectEvent $formatDrivejob StateChanged -Action {
        Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) (' USB slot = Job #{0} ({1}) complete.' -f $sender.Id, $sender.Name)
        [media.SystemSounds]::("Hand").Play()
        foreach ($i in $formatDrivejob){
           if ($i.State -eq "Completed")
           {
             $letter = $formatDrivejob | receive-job | select -Last 1
             Write-Host "Drive has finished:" $letter
             $formatDrivejob.Remove($i)
           } 
        }
        $jobEvent | Unregister-Event
    }
}
Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1-eq1) #Loop until next event
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Receive-job` to get the results:

```
# initialize the array
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$formatDrivejob
if ($eventType -eq 2) {
    $driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
    $driveLabel = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
    Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) "USB igang = " $driveLetter
    # Execute process if drive matches specified condition(s)
    $formatDrivejob += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $formatDrive -ArgumentList $driveLetter
    $jobEvent = Register-ObjectEvent $formatDrivejob StateChanged -Action {
        Write-Host (Get-Date -Format s) (' USB slot = Job #{0} ({1}) complete.' -f $sender.Id, $sender.Name)
        [media.SystemSounds]::("Hand").Play()
        foreach ($i in $formatDrivejob){
           if ($i.State -eq "Completed")
           {
             $letter = $formatDrivejob | receive-job | select -Last 1
             Write-Host "Drive has finished:" $letter
             $formatDrivejob.Remove($i)
           } 
        }
        $jobEvent | Unregister-Event
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But see comment for DarkLite1. Apparently I can´t use `wait job` as it stop the script form triggering new USBs inserted while a job is running. I need to do multiple jobs in parallel

Comment: You are right. But it also works without the wait-job. I updated the answer

Comment: @S.Spieker true, but it can happen that you are trying to retrieve a job result that is not there yet, i.e. when the job is not finished. Best practice would be to either wait for the job to finish or launch them all simultaneously and handle the job output when they're all done.

Comment: Yes! this seems promising. But when I plug in three USBs it wil first output `USB igang = K:`, `UBS igang = F:`, `USB igang = J:`..... But then only the last gives out a finished result like: `Drive has finished:`, `Drive has finished:`, `Drive has finished: J:`

Comment: Ah, of course. We should use an array of jobs and just receive the one which is completed. I will enhance the answer

Comment: Indeed, I've also updated my answer with how I think I would do it. In any case, both approaches should work.

Comment: I feel like it's so close to work! thought this error

Comment: `Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.`

Comment: Also see my full code in buttom of my question. I've placed the code I tried with

Comment: @S.Spieker it says the error is at line with `$formatDrivejob += Start-Job -Sc..`

Comment: @S.Spieker Okay. I've tried to do the array as in @DarkLite1 answer. `$formatDrivejob = @()` but now the error is `An event with the name 'StateChanged' does not exist`

Comment: @S.Spieker I never got away with the error as described above. But I think you answer is the right solution to the question, so I've marked it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try an approach like this:

```
$DrivesToHandle = 5
$formatDrivejob = @()

Do {
    if ($eventType -eq 2) {
        $DrivesToHandle -= 1
        $driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
        $driveLabel = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
        write-host (Get-Date -format s) "USB igang = $driveLetter" 
        # Execute process if drive matches specified condition(s)
        $formatDrivejob += Start-Job -ScriptBlock $formatDrive -ArgumentList $driveLetter
    }
} while ($DrivesToHandle -ne 0)

# Wait for all jobs to finish
$formatDrivejob | Wait-Job | Out-Null

# Retrieve the job results
$JobResults = $formatDrivejob | Receive-Job

foreach ($Job in $JobResults) {
    Write-Host (get-date -format s) "Job result of job ID $($Job.Id): " $Job
}

# Remove all jobs
$formatDrivejob | Remove-Job -Force
```

When you work with `jobs` you can use `Wait-Job` to wait for the job to finish. But you also have to retrieve the job results, that's done by using the `Receive-Job` CmdLet.

Comment: Thanks! But with `Wait-Job` I can't do multiple USBs at once. I won´t trigger a new USB plugged in before the job is done, if I have `Wait-Job` in the code

Comment: True, you can take out the part to wait and retrieve the results and do that after the loop, when all jobs have been started. Then you can retrieve all job results at once. Don't forget to change `$formatDrivejob = Start-Job` to `$formatDrivejob += Start-Job` to have an `array` of job results that you can iterate.

Comment: Thanks! but it dosen't seem like it ever going out of the while loop, so I don´t know where to place the `Wait-Job`

Comment: Thanks! I like this. But as you have to define how many devices to handle, I think I will go with Spiekers solution :)